# How to change color when click active or inactive in php using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I want to change color of `<i>` tag when I click for active and inactive

**My ajax code**

```
$('.factive').click(function(){
    var factiveId = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('controller/ajax-product-active.php?factiveId='+factiveId,
    {},function(data)
    {  
        $('#product-active').html(data);
    });
});
```

**ajax-product-active.php**

```
if ($csrow['status']=='Active') {
    $update_status = mysqli_query($conn,"update products set status = 'Deactive' where id = '{$factiveId}'");

    echo "<a id='$csrow[id]' class='factive' style='cursor: pointer;'  onclick='productActive($csrow[id])'>
        <i class='fa fa-circle pactive' aria-hidden='true'style='color:red' title='Deactive'></i></a>";

}elseif ($csrow['status']=='Deactive') {

    $update_status = mysqli_query($conn,"update products set status = 'Active' where id = '{$factiveId}'");

    echo "<a id='$csrow[id]' class='factive' style='cursor: pointer;'  onclick='productActive($csrow[id])'>
        <i class='fa fa-circle pactive' aria-hidden='true'style='color:#12bc00' title='Active'></i></a>";
}
```

This code is running successfully but color is changing only first. Whether click on any tag

Comment: Would advise doing this in CSS or by adding a Class.

Comment: this is already here check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598213/how-to-bind-events-on-ajax-loaded-content

Comment: dear sir, how to add class in ajax please help

Comment: Add you current html code in question

Comment: where do you get `$csrow['status']` from?

Comment: @CodeGodie in listing page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the active element then you have to get the current value(Active,Deactive) and change the class accordingly

```js
$('.factive').click(function(){
    var currentVal = $(this).find('i').attr('title');
    var addCls = 'active';
    var removeCls = 'deactive';
    var title = 'Active';
    if(currentVal == 'Active'){
      addCls = 'deactive';
      removeCls = 'active';
      title = 'Deactive';
    }
    $(this).find('i').addClass(addCls).removeClass(removeCls);
    $(this).find('i').attr('title',title);
    $(this).find('i').text(title);
 });
```

```css
.active{color:#12bc00}
.deactive{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='1' class='factive active' style='cursor: pointer;'>
  <i class='fa fa-circle pactive' aria-hidden='true' title='Active'>Active</i>
  
<a id='2' class='factive deactive' style='cursor: pointer;'>
  <i class='fa fa-circle pactive' aria-hidden='true' title='Deactive'>Deactive</i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with AJAX requests a rule, I use, is to make all the data transferred between backend to client into JSON. Therefore PHP will send its response in JSON, and JS will expect a JSON object back. With that said, let's modify your HTML/CSS/JS in this manner (Note: I am excluding all unrelated info) :

```
<style>
    .product {
        color: red
    }

    .product.active {
        color: green;
    }
</style>

<a href="#" class="product">
    <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
</a>

<script>
    $('.product').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        var id = $link.attr('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'controller/ajax-product-active.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {productId: id},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.active) {
                    $link.addClass('active');
                } else {
                    $link.removeClass('active');
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the above modification, I am calling your link `.product` because that makes the most sense to me, since a "product" can be "active" or "inactive". In the JS, I am changing your `$.post` to `$.ajax` to add the `dataType: 'json'` option which tells it that the expected response should be JSON. We expect the return to be something like `{"active":"true"}` or `{"active":"false"}`. Based on that, we either add or remove the `.active` class to the `.product` element. Depending on the classes, CSS applies accordingly.

On the PHP side, we would need to do something like this (again, im only including relevant code. `$status` is the same as the `$csrow['status']` you provided):

```
$response = [];
if ($status === 'Active') {
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "update products set status = 'Deactive' where id = '{$factiveId}'");
   $response['active'] = false;
} elseif ($status === 'Deactive') {
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "update products set status = 'Active' where id = '{$factiveId}'");
   $response['active'] = true;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Notice that we're building the `$response` array, then returning that to JS as JSON.

Give this structure a go, it will make your code cleaner, and prepare you for a RESTful architecture.