# JavaScript functions not working when HTML is loaded through PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, ajax

I am trying to load in some HTML trough Ajax. The HTML has a funtion assigned to it with the ONCLICK attribute. Now when i execute the code the function is completely ignored. The HTML is loaded in perfectly.

Below is a simplified version of what i am trying to do.

PHP code for creating the HTML (gethtml.php):

```
$html = '<a onclick="thefunction()">Click this to trigger JS function</a>';
$data = array(
    'html' => $html
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Loading the HTML trough javascript (main.html):

```
function load_HTML()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"actions/gethtml.php",
            method:"POST",
            dataType:"JSON",
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#container_id').html(data.html);
            }
        })
    }
```

Javascript function for loaded HTML (main.html):

```
function thefunction(){
   //any function
}
```

I hope anyone can help me!

Comment: Where does `data.tabledata` come from? Your PHP is certainly not supplying it. A quick look at your JS console would have quickly pointed you to some issues.

Comment: Where are you getting `tabledata` ?

Comment: Oops! My bad, i changed it.

Comment: did you try onclick="return thefunction();" instead of onclick="thefunction()"?

Comment: So it's working now? You need to check your JS console and figure out which error it is yelling at you...

Comment: Check browser devtools console for errors.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No that was just in the example for this question.

Comment: Umm okay, well that was a useless example. Anyways, what error are you getting in your JS console?

Comment: @elk Also not working..

Comment: @MonkeyZeus None, the whole thing is being ignored

Comment: Should work fine as seen in this demo https://jsfiddle.net/bz5oe2yq/

Comment: Use event delegation for dynamically created elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598213/how-to-bind-events-on-ajax-loaded-content

Comment: Without onclick: http://jsfiddle.net/7Lc18vdb/2/

Comment: @BillyG Thank you!! That worked perfectly!

Comment: @MichaelRöhrig he didn't mention using jQuery.

Comment: @WiboKuipers you shouldn't be using the onClick html functionality, it's considered deprecated and a bad practice. If you're using some framework create bindings with it and if not you're still better off with using event listeners - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: @Dropout I assumed he did because of his code, where he does ;-)