# slideToggle function stops working when toggling ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slidetoggle

I have two buttons, which change the views with ng-show, and I have a filter on the default view. Filter is a dropdown that works with SlideToggle() and it works until I click the other button and go to the second view and when I click bac to the default one, dropdown stops working. 
I've inspected it in Chrome, nothing happens
this is the code for the dropdown:

```
<div ng-if="filter.entity === 'user'" class="col-md-12 filter-group">
<h5 class="open">Age<span class="caret"></span></h5>
   <div class="filter-group-items filter">
       <div>Age
         <rzslider rz-slider-model="filter.ageMin" rz-slider high="filter.ageMax" rz-slider-options="sliderOptionsAmount">
         </rzslider>
       </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

This it the js

```
  $(".open").click(() => {
  $(".filter").slideToggle()
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the same like binding events on AJAX loaded content, see [How to bind Events on Ajax loaded Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598213/how-to-bind-events-on-ajax-loaded-content)

jQuery event binding for dynamic content should look like this:

`$(document).on("click", ".open", () => {
    $(".filter").slideToggle();
});`

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be the fact that JQuery is updating the DOM and angular does not know about it. I would try doing all in angular and it would work