# onclick() function to fetch button value to text box working only one time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My `onclick()` function to fetch a button's value to a text box is working only one time. Here is a JQuery function to add the button's value to an input text box

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    var word = document.getElementById("str").value + ' ' + fired_button;
    document.getElementById("str").value = word;            
});
```

HTML code

```
<button class="btn m-1 btn-secondary" id="sel0"  value="<?php echo $row2['W1']; ?>"><?php echo 
row2['W1']; ?> </button> 
<button class="btn m-1 btn-secondary"  id="sel1"  value="<?php echo $row2['W2']; ?>"><?php echo 
$row2['W2']; ?></button>
<button class="btn m-1 btn-secondary"  id="sel2"   value="<?php echo $row2['W3']; ?>"><?php echo 
$row2['W3']; ?></button>
<button class="btn m-1 btn-secondary"  id="sel3"   value="<?php echo $row2['W4']; ?>"><?php echo 
$row2['W4']; ?></button>
```

After clicking the start button it's working fine and displaying the values of the clicked button in the textbox

[image: here after clicking the start button its working fine and displaying the values of clicked button in text box]

But after I fetch the next row in the query, the AJAX values are being changed and the `onclick` function is not working.

It's a quiz project. I want `onclick` to fetch the button value into the textbox, which is working right on the first call. But, after fetching the second row by clicking next button, then it's not working.

Comment: How are you "fetching the second row"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598213/how-to-bind-events-on-ajax-loaded-content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: `$("button").click` only applies to elements that exist at the time, use event delegation, `$(document).on("click", "button", ...`

Comment: @manav using ajax

Comment: @freedomn-m or khalander bankapur, please post an answer to the question now that it is solved.

Comment: @Kirby it's a *very* common question, see duplicate link.

Comment: @kirby sure posted the answer:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {

    var fired_button = $(this).val();
    var word = document.getElementById("str").value + ' ' + fired_button;
    document.getElementById("str").value = word;
        
});
```

/*
here we are using document as entity from which in the document if we click the button tag this function will be executed*/

Comment: Please provide an explanation about your solution, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer