# Button click events not triggering on saved HTML with Angular controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I saved contents of a HTML page (with UI-Grid control, drop down, input texts etc.) in SQL Server database.

I have another page where I am fetching the saved HTML and assigning it to a div inside the page.

The saved HTML is rendered correctly, but for buttons present on the page, click events are not fired. I have the same functions as in the main page in this page. Also checked that the HTML I need is rendered correctly.

I am doing the following -

1)PageA.HTML has an element -

enter code here
blah

2)save all div contents from PageA to the database.

3)Page B - has a div - main

4)I main.innerHTML = the saved content from PageA.

It renders the page correctly.

However I am not able to do the action on ng-click="blah('blah')"

That event is not triggering.

What is the be best way to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe you need to recreate the DOM of the page, if you are loading the HTML after the page finish loading the DOM

Comment: The HTML is most probably loaded through AJAX. The event listeners for the loaded html, should be assigned to the `document` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598231/994006

Comment: please share code as well

Comment: Added the code for what I am doing above.