# jquery grid dynamically loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

To have a jquery grid in a typical page `gridePage.html` with some HTML and JavaScript code I do

```
 $("#gridtable").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        data:  [
            {'type': 'aType', 
             'area': 'anArea'}]
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Now consider I have a `main.html` page which loads the `gridePage.html` via ajax call and put it in a div.

```
<div id="content"></div>

$.ajax({
        url : "/gridePage.html",         
        success : function(data) { //the data is all the content in gridePage.html
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
```

The javascript code in `gridePage.html` ( `$("#gridtable").jq...` ) is not working any more.

If I change  `gridePage.html` and wrap the JavaScript in `setTimeout` it will work as it will delay the execuation of `$("#gridtable").jq...`

As you can see I have add  `("#gridtable").jq...` to ajax `success` or ( and also tried `complete` ) but still it is not working.

I see a topic at [How to bind Events on Ajax loaded Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598213/how-to-bind-events-on-ajax-loaded-content) seems same problem, but i don't know how can I use it with grid

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$('#content').load("/gridePage.html", function() {
  $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    data: [{
      'type': 'aType',
      'area': 'anArea'
    }]
  }).trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```